# I used internet explorer to sound an alarm, now it moves to microsoft edge. What should I do?`

Tags: internet-explorer

So I have this program

```
Public Shared Async Function SingSongs3() As Task
    ias.NavigateTillComplete("https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ifCWN5pJGIE")
    Await Task.Delay(15000)
    ias.NavigateTillComplete("http://google.com")
End Function
```

If something needs to be done, it explore youtube, play a song, and after 15 seconds go to google.com works fine.

Now,

we have this issue

https://superuser.com/questions/1586011/why-some-websites-are-redirected-to-microsoft-edge

What should I do?

Is there a way to put an mp4 file into project and play that file? Or do something like that? How.

What about all other programs that automate internet explorer. Will they die too?

Can we automate microsoft edge instead?

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure which version of the IE browser and which Edge browser you are using on your side. I assume that you are using the IE 11 browser.

I think that to make an alarm, you do not need to automate the IE browser. You can use the inbuilt alarm app or try to develop it using a simple C# application.

Further, I try to visit the Youtube and it works fine in the IE 11 browser.

I suggest you try to manually open the youtube in the IE browser and check whether it launch the Edge browser. Something like below.

[image]

If the site gets launches in the Edge browser then it can be possible that this issue caused by the configuration of any specific group policy on your machine.

To verify it, you can refer to the step below.

1. Open the Local group policy editor.
2. Browse through the path below.

> Computer configuration-> Administrative templates-> Windows
> components-> Internet explorer

3. Find the policy **Send all sites not included in the Enterprise mode site list to Microsoft edge**.

[image]

4. If it is enabled then probably it is causing this issue.

If this policy applied unknowingly then you can disable it may help to fix the issue.

If this policy applied for a purpose and you still want to automate the browser for your alarm app then you can try to use selenium web driver to automate the Edge browser.

References:

1. [Use WebDriver (Chromium) for test automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver-chromium?tabs=c-sharp)
2. [WebDriver (EdgeHTML)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/webdriver)

It also can be possible that the issue caused by something else. You can try to provide more information about your development environment and information about the issue. It can help us to understand the issue in a better way.

Comment: Great. I will try one by one. Can we automate microsoft edge like we automate internet explorer?

Comment: My internet explorer is version 11.1082. It's kind of weird that it can't open youtube

Comment: Yes, you can automate the Edge browser like you automate the IE. If there are any Windows updates available for your Windows OS then update your OS will update the IE browser. It may fix the issue. If no suggestion works then try to reset the IE browser. Also, try to visit the site in private mode and see whether it works.